# How can I search for brackets?

Tags: discussion, search, tag-search

I'm trying to search for `["content-available"]` or `[content-available]`.

But I **don't** want to search for them as a `tag`. They are exactly the string that I want to search for :D

I'm hoping to find something like

```
notification["content-available"]
```